# Find a sequence in $[0,\ln 4]$

Tags: integration, limits

Find an $a_1, a_2, \dots$ sequence in the interval $[0,\ln 4]$, such that for any $x<y$ positive integers
$$|a_x-a_y|\geq \dfrac{1}{y}$$

I know the well known
$$a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$
sequence, and I tried making new sequences from that, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your sequence $a_n$ is contained in your intervall. For example, $a_2=-\frac{1}{2}\notin [0,ln(4)]$.

Comment: The sequence is just a starting point...I know that doesn’t work...